# How can I get start and end dates of daterange in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have `daterange` type column in a table. I want to select all rows which have end date in their daterange that is in the future.

Can I somehow extract start and end values of the daterange in a query?

Comment: as @Stanislav said, ` select * from TABLE where upper(COLUMN) > now();` should work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suppose, you can use `upper(anyrange)` function to get this value. According to the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-range.html#RANGE-FUNCTIONS-TABLE).

Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE upper(daterange_type_colum) > current_date();
```